# Pthread conditionals

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I can post my code if necessary, but my question is primarily conceptual. I am implementing Gaussian elimination with threading. I have p pthreads operating on an nxn matrix in column major order. Before any p-thread can start operating on a column, row operations must be done to move the row with the largest value in that column up to the diagonal. So I need every thread to wait and then operate in unison. Currently, at each column, Each thread checks its id, the one with id=0 will perform the row operations. My problem is how to get all the threads but id=0 to wait and then operate in Unison.

I've tried using mutex locks and conditionals. These don't seem to work because they give all access rights to a single thread. From what I understand, one can only block a thread in this manner by having it request a lock where one already exists, so it must wait. This would be a problem in my case because I don't want any of the non-0 threads to have a lock, once they are unlocked I want them to operate freely until they finish their work on column.

I tried to avoid Mutex locks by simply having a global "colReady" variable set to 0. The non-zero threads while loop until colReady = True. Logically this makes perfect sense, but it has not worked programatically.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define n 20
#define numThr 3

double **matrix;
int pivotReady[n] = { 0 };

pthread_cond_t cond_pivot_ready;
pthread_mutex_t cond_mutex;

int swapRows (int row1, int row2)
{
    double *tempRow = matrix[row1];
    matrix[row1] = matrix[row2];
    matrix[row2] = tempRow;
    return 0;
}

void randinit ()
{
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < n + 1; j++) {
            matrix[i][j] = drand48 ();
        }
    }
}

void rowReduce (void *arg);

void printMatrix ()
{
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < n + 1; j++) {
            printf (" %4.2f ", matrix[i][j]);
        }
        printf ("\n");
    }
}

int main ()
{
    pthread_cond_init (&cond_pivot_ready, NULL);
    pthread_mutex_init (&cond_mutex, NULL);

    int i, j;
    double temp;
    pthread_t p_threads[numThr];
    pthread_attr_t attr;
    pthread_attr_init (&attr);

    //create matrix
    matrix = malloc (sizeof (double *) * n);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        *(matrix + i) = malloc (sizeof (double) * (n + 1));
    }

    randinit ();

    for (i = 0; i < numThr; i++) {
        pthread_create (&p_threads[i], &attr, rowReduce, (void *) ((long) i));
    }

    for (i = 0; i < numThr; i++) {
        pthread_join (p_threads[i], NULL);
    }
    printf ("Final Matrix:\n");
    printMatrix ();

    return 0;
}

void rowReduce (void *arg)
{
    int id = (int) arg;
    int i, pivot, row;
    double ratio, temp, max;
    int maxRow;

    for (pivot = 0; pivot < n - 1; pivot++) {

        //PIVOT THREAD
        if (id == 0) {
            pthread_mutex_lock (&cond_mutex);
            max = matrix[pivot][pivot]
                maxRow = pivot;
            for (i = pivot + 1; i < n; i++) {
                temp = matrix[i][pivot];
                if (temp > max) {
                    max = temp;
                    maxRow = i;
                }
            }
            swapRows (pivot, maxRow);

            pivotReady[pivot] = 1;
            pthread_cond_signal (&cond_pivot_ready);

            for (row = pivot + 1 + id; row < n; row += numThr) {

                ratio = matrix[row][pivot] / matrix[pivot][pivot];
                printf ("t1: row = %d, piv = %d, ratio = %f\n", row, pivot,
                        ratio);
                for (int i = pivot; i < n + 1; i++) {
                    matrix[row][i] -= ratio * matrix[pivot][i];
                }
            }
            pthread_mutex_unlock (&cond_mutex);
        }
        //NON-PIVOT THREAD
        else {
            pthread_mutex_lock (&cond_mutex);
            while (!(pivotReady[pivot])) {
                pthread_cond_wait (&cond_pivot_ready, &cond_mutex);
            }

            for (row = pivot + 1 + id; row < n; row += numThr) {
                ratio = matrix[row][pivot] / matrix[pivot][pivot];
                for (int i = pivot; i < n + 1; i++) {
                    matrix[row][i] -= ratio * matrix[pivot][i];
                }
            }
            pthread_mutex_unlock (&cond_mutex);

        }

    }

    //printf("rowReduce called with id = %d\n", id);
    pthread_exit (0);
}
```

This program SHOULD print a random matrix that has been put in upper triangular form.

Comment: You should look into `pthread_barrier_wait()`.

Comment: Side note: Unless the matrix is HUUUGE (really huge!), trying to create a concurrent version of the algorithm is not paying off. In a more abstract way: The application which would use this would probably have to solve that problem many times and you would better run parallel versions of the single threaded algorithm. To make it pay off at all, you would have to find a lock-free approach to the algorithm. Using data parallelism on the other hand would be a good idea. Keyword: SIMD.

Comment: I haven't looked at your code, but based on your description why not have the main thread sort the rows then start the other threads after the matrix is prepared?

Comment: If you have threads **waiting** on **row operations** to complete, is there any benefit to using threads in this situation? (more than nominal?)

Comment: @MichaelBurr The matrix must be resorted after each column is digested. So The parallelization occurs at each column but Since the entire matrix is augmented at every column iteration, we cannot simply put the matrix into a state that will satisfy the threads for the entire program

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to hold the `cond_mutex` while you are accessing `pivotReady[pivot]`, because that's the only shared state it protects.

You also need to use `pthread_cond_broadcast()` rather than `pthread_cond_signal()`, because you need *all* the waiting threads to proceed once the pivot is ready.

After a minor refactoring so that the row processing code isn't repeated, it looks like:

```
for (pivot = 0; pivot < n - 1; pivot++) {

    //PIVOT THREAD
    if (id == 0) {
        max = matrix[pivot][pivot];
        maxRow = pivot;
        for (i = pivot + 1; i < n; i++) {
            temp = matrix[i][pivot];
            if (temp > max) {
                max = temp;
                maxRow = i;
            }
        }
        swapRows (pivot, maxRow);

        pthread_mutex_lock (&cond_mutex);
        pivotReady[pivot] = 1;
        pthread_cond_broadcast (&cond_pivot_ready);
        pthread_mutex_unlock (&cond_mutex);
    }
    //NON-PIVOT THREAD
    else {
        pthread_mutex_lock (&cond_mutex);
        while (!(pivotReady[pivot])) {
            pthread_cond_wait (&cond_pivot_ready, &cond_mutex);
        }
        pthread_mutex_unlock (&cond_mutex);
    }

    for (row = pivot + 1 + id; row < n; row += numThr) {
        ratio = matrix[row][pivot] / matrix[pivot][pivot];
        for (int i = pivot; i < n + 1; i++) {
            matrix[row][i] -= ratio * matrix[pivot][i];
        }
    }
}
```